# column-count is being exceeded on page and column-width is ignored

Tags: html, css

Thanks to the help I received on a question I asked previously, I decided to use the column framework for my webpage. It seemed straightforward to declare a number of columns to use, but I am stuck with my column count being exceeded.

For example, I want 3 columns, but I end up with 4.

I tried adding `column-width` and this is just being ignored when rendering the page.

I tried setting the width to be `700px` because 4 `700px` columns would not fit on my screen; the width was ignored so this didn't help.

Preferably, I'd like to just set a column-width and let the page adapt to various screen sizes, so that a large screen (much larger than my small laptop) won't be limited to just 3 columns.

Setting an absolute maximum number of columns would be a less ideal solution. Can anyone help?

```css
.masonry-brick {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
}

.masonry-brick img {
 max-height: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
}

.container {
 -webkit-column-count: 3;
        -moz-column-count: 3;
         column-count: 3
 -webkit-column-width: 700px;
        -moz-column-width: 700px;
 column-width: 700px;
 display: flex;
}

.title {
 height: 30em;
 width: 30em;
 padding: 1em;
}

.center {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center; 
 text-align: center;
}

.red {
 background-color: rgba(255, 63, 63, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
    <div class="masonry-brick title red center">
        <h1><b>Projects - Front End</b></h1>
    </div>
  
    <div class="masonry-brick">
        <img src="https://pixy.org/images/placeholder.png">
    </div>
   
    <div class="masonry-brick">
        <img src="https://pixy.org/images/placeholder.png">
    </div>

    <!-- This should be displayed in the first column as the page should have 3 columns -->
    <div class="masonry-brick title red center">
        <h1><b>Project - Back End</b></h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Viewing the snippet result in full screen gives a good depiction of what's happening.

Comment: Note that your `container` should be `display:block` instead of `display:flex`. The flex container is resizing elements to fix, since all of your `.masonry-brick` elements have a percentage width instead of a fixed width. I'm not sure this completely solves the issue but puts you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.masonry-brick {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 1em 0;
    break-inside: avoid-column;
}

.container {
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 0;
    column-fill: balance;
}

.masonry-brick img {
    width: 100%;
}

.title {
    height: 25vw;
}

.center { 
 text-align: center;
}

.red {
 background-color: rgba(255, 63, 63, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="masonry-brick title red center">
    <h1><b>Projects - Front End</b></h1>
   </div>
            
            <div class="masonry-brick title red center">
    <h1><b>Projects - Front End</b></h1>
   </div>
            
            <div class="masonry-brick">
    <img src="https://pixy.org/images/placeholder.png">
   </div>
            
            <div class="masonry-brick">
    <img src="https://pixy.org/images/placeholder.png">
   </div>
   
   <div class="masonry-brick">
    <img src="https://pixy.org/images/placeholder.png">
   </div>
   
      <!-- This should be displayed in the first column as the page should have 3 columns -->
   <div class="masonry-brick title red center">
    <h1><b>Project - Back End</b></h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

I noticed there was a missing semicolon after `column-count: 3`. Also, you can use `break-inside: avoid` to keep individual columns intact.

I added a few more boxes to show the proper column behavior. `display: flex` and `display: inline-block` interfered with normal behavior, so I removed those, as well as margins between the different columns.

For a more in-depth understanding of why the columns appear the way they do, Friso Van Dijk's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46919711/5732397) is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The column-width property is prioritised over the column-count. So, if you remove the column-width property, you'll end up with 3 columns.
That's not exactly what you want though, so you'd combine the statement into `columns: 200px 3;` That gives you 3 columns with a minimum width of 700px. Realise that will net you 2 columns on a 1920x1080 monitor, so not sure what you call a tiny screen in this scenario (just note that >25% of users are mobile-only nowadays, but that's another topic).

Also, you say have the comment `<!-- This should be displayed in the first column as the page should have 3 columns -->`. That is not true. You make the assumption that you stack the elements from left to right, but in fact, as the name column suggests, your browser checks how many fit next to each other in the window and then starts stacking from top to bottom.

I added a blue dotted line to visually separate the columns. You can remove `display: inline-block;` to stop a new column being created with overflow and `break-inside: avoid;` to stop elements from breaking across columns.

I hope this answers your question as best as possible. It seems to be more of a knowledge question than a specific implementation problem. Best of luck!

```css
.masonry-brick {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 1em 1em 1em 1em;                  
}

.masonry-brick img {
 max-height: 100%;
 max-width: 100%
}

.container {
-webkit-columns: 250px;
   -moz-columns: 250px;
        columns: 250px;
        
  -webkit-column-rule: 4px dotted blue;
     -moz-column-rule: 4px dotted blue;
          column-rule: 4px dotted blue;
}

.title {
 height: 30em;
 padding: 1em;
}

.center {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 text-align: center;
}

.red {
 background-color: rgba(255, 63, 63, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
   <div class="masonry-brick title red center">
    <h1><b>Projects - Front End</b></h1>
   </div>
  
   <div class="masonry-brick">
    <img src="https://pixy.org/images/placeholder.png">
   </div>
   
   <div class="masonry-brick">
    <img src="https://pixy.org/images/placeholder.png">
   </div>
   
      <!-- This should be displayed in the first column as the page should have 3 columns -->
   <div class="masonry-brick title red center">
    <h1><b>Project - Back End</b></h1>
   </div>
</div>
```